# Circular reasoning about the existence of other minds

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mind, social-epistemology

1. If I use the IBE argument to justify my belief in the existence of other minds, but I don't know how the argument reached its conclusion, can I just trust the experts who formulated the argument or will it be circular reasoning?
2. If I rely on my common sense and believe in the existence of other minds, but I do not know whether the beliefs of common sense are justified, can I rely on experts who say that we can trust common sense, or will it be circular reasoning?

Comment: we accept very many things on authority. it is good and useful to question authority, but if it is legitimate authority we should believe it (defeasibly etc.). i don't know why it is light is a wave and a particle, but i do believe it (though in this instance i'm not entirely sure what it means). and i mean that especially for explanations

Comment: What about the existence of other minds? In order to rely on experts, you need to believe in the existence of other minds. But if you believe in the existence of other minds, then there is no need to rely on arguments and experts.

Comment: i don't think solipsists need to be committed to radical skepticism about authority, and i'm not sure it is any more reasonable for them than anyone else. so it's not begging the question imvho. whether or not we have first person phenomenological evidence for other minds is open to debate. i suspect so, but not with complete certainty

Comment: OK. If I do not fully understand the IBE argument in favor of the existence of other minds and simply rely on the knowledge and experience of the experts who formulated this argument, will this be circular reasoning?

Comment: idt it's circular just cos it's about other minds (rater than say particles of physics). that's all i mean. is an appeal to legitimate authority an implicit appeal to other minds? i don't think so... it's more likely a form of induction

Comment: my "answer" on the question about ad hominems and chat gpt may contradict this in part, and this isn't a great analogy, but is an appeal to a calculator's skill at arithmetic a fallacy?

Comment: I do not know.
I want to ask you.
Circular reasoning is when the conclusion lies in the premises.

If I believe that the existence of other minds is the best explanation for other people's behavior because the experts said so, then my reasoning is circular, and therefore I cannot use this justification for my belief in the existence of other minds, because this requires already believing in the existence of other minds.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: If I ignore the fact that this is circular reasoning, I still can't use that excuse because I have to first believe in other minds in order to believe in the existence of experts.

Comment: i disagree. cats are very good at landing on their feet, even if they do lack a qualitative sense of balance.

Comment: So I can rely on my common sense and the IBE argument to justify my belief in the existence of other minds even though I don't fully understand how these two justifications work and I fully trust the experts who research these questions? Will it be rational?

Comment: maybe make up your own mind on what sort of claims include an appeal to other minds. for me, it wouldn't. HTH :)

Comment: IBE says that the existence of other minds is the best explanation for the behavior we observe in other people. I don't know how IBE came to this conclusion because every expert who formulates this argument adds his criteria and his observations and experiments. I did not find anywhere an explanation of how IBE comes to this conclusion. I can trust the experts to make the right conclusions based on their observations and research since they have more information than I do.

Comment: But now the following situation arises: 1. I believe that other people have minds, because this is the best explanation for other people's behavior. 2. Why is this the best explanation? 3. Because experts say so. But to believe the experts, I have to believe that they have minds.

Comment: I believe in the existence of other minds because of common sense.
Therefore, I can first rely on common sense and then on IBE, but I do not know whether the beliefs of common sense are justified. For this, I need to rely on the experts again.

I can treat experts simply as a reliable source and not conscious people, but I also need to explain why I consider it a reliable source.

I seem to be confused in this circular reasoning

Comment: @forlove1: It's quite consistent for me to insist that I am a p-zombie and that -- by Turing's convention of other minds -- all humans are p-zombies. There's no evidence against it. If you write an answer, please keep this in mind.

Comment: Will it be circular reasoning to rely on experts at IBE? I understand that common sense justifies the belief in the existence of other minds, but I want to get an answer to my question.

Comment: surely it would be a lie @Corbin so consistent with what?

Comment: IBE doesn't need expert mind but a reliable source, what's this source? How you infer from best explanation that some person was around after you saw a human sized footprint? How you infer what exists on that table is an apple instead of an orange? How you infer what's the best way to solve Riemann hypothesis (via analytic or algebraic number theory)? Possibly you can infer the first two but not the last since you may not get trained enough or formed certain intuition from your own experiences' supervision about tackling Riemann conjecture. Most people infer other minds from their parents...

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I would not recommend reliance on authority. It often fails. It seems reasonable to infer the existence of other minds from behaviour. I see no incompatibility with common sense. I do not see any circular reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

OK let's take some branching possibilities. We meet someone, call them nibroc, who we ask if they are a p zombie. There are a few different scenarios that may be occurring

1. nibroc is not a zombie
2. nibroc is a zombie and is an authority on that
3. nibroc is a zombie but is not an authority on that but some people are
4. nibroc is a zombie but is not an authority on that and no-one is

1 means we should not be solipsists. 2 means not all appeal to authority on solipsism assumes other minds^. 3 repeats 1 and 2 for others like nibroc. 4 is the only option: but how can you decide that no-one is an authority ***without just assuming that no-one is***?

Anyway, there are reasons (ones which are not obviously question begging) to suppose such an authority can exist. The bible is oft said to be an authority on morality; it does not have a mind. It is trivially easy to imagine - though not establish that they are - someone who is an authority on whether they themselves have a mind: absolutely anyone with a mind, etc. (I'm just a moron on a forum).

^ you are begging the question if only people claiming to be zombies should be believed, at least if you have not already established their authority or their lack of a mind.

### tl;dr

I don't think anyone has shown that all arguments from authority assumes other minds, nor that no-one is an authority on solipsism.

Comment: For what it's worth, I am a p-zombie. This isn't an authoritative claim, though; it's just words from my fingers to your screen.

Comment: great. sorry but you lack the authority necessary to make your claim believable @Corbin i definitely am NOT a p zombie, and i do not believe you are either

Comment: does everyone who claims to be a p zombie necessarily lack the authority to make that claim @Corbin believable etc.?

Comment: It's merely a disagreement. What might vex you is the lack of evidence for *either* side of the disagreement!

Comment: i suppose the issue is that for solipsists you shouldn't believe what others tell you because only other minds are worthy of being... trusted @Corbin ?

Comment: What if experts tell you not to trust authority? This is the case with Philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

In the Heideggerian œuvre other minds are included from the start in Dasein's primary mode of [*Mitsein*](https://culturalstudiesnow.blogspot.com/2022/12/meaning-of-heideggers-mitsein-being.html) (being-with). E.g. from *Being & Time* (116):

> [The] positive Interpretation of Dasein which we have so far
> given, already forbids us to start with the formal givenness of the
> "I", if our purpose is to answer the question of the "who" in a way
> which is pheno­menally adequate. In clarifying Being-in-the-world we
> have shown that a bare subject without a world never 'is' proximally,
> nor is it ever given. And so in the end an isolated "I" without Others
> is just as far from being proximally given. If, however, 'the Others'
> already *are there with us* [*mit da sind*] in Being-in-the-world, and
> if this is ascertained phenomenally, even this should not mislead us
> into supposing that the *ontological* structure of what is thus
> 'given' is obvious, requiring no investigation. Our task is to make
> visible phenomenally the species to which this Dasein-with in closest
> everydayness belongs, and to Interpret it in a way which is
> ontologically appropriate.

To quote the [IEP](https://iep.utm.edu/phenom/#SH2b):

> [The phenomenal reduction] enables the phenomenologist to go “back to
> the ‘things themselves'”(Husserl 2001, 168), meaning back to the ways
> that things are actually given in experience. Indeed, it is precisely
> here, in the realm of phenomena, that Husserl believes we will find
> that indubitable evidence that will ultimately serve as the foundation
> for every scientific discipline. As such, it is vital that we are able
> to look beyond the prejudices of common sense realism, and accept
> things as actually given.

Hence the phenomenological starting point is direct experience which is culturally embedded from its earliest development.

Comment: you might want to add a commentary on what you think heidegger means here?

Comment: Everything boils down to the fact that if I trust experts, it will mean that I already believe in the existence of other minds. That is, the conclusion will lie in one of the premises. As far as I understand, we can rely on experts in any situation, but not in matters of the existence of other minds. It is impossible to say that I believe in other minds because experts say that other minds exist, because in order to rely on experts you have to believe that they have minds.

Comment: why does an expert need a mind? that's all i'm confused about @Arti is ai really that bad? haha

Comment: Of course, we can rely on experts simply as a reliable source that does not require a conscious mind, then it will not be circular reasoning. But then I need to explain why I consider it a reliable source. Here you can rely solely on your own experience, but since I lack knowledge, I need to rely on experts again, which will again become circular.

Comment: oh i get it: either you believe the expert because they have a mind or you don't know what makes them reliable. right @Arti ? fwiw, i believe professional peer review processes because doing so definitely seems more reliable than asking random people. it may be the case that i only care who is reliable because i believe in other minds. dunno

Comment: simply an expert who has a mind is a more reliable source than any unconscious source. But in any case, I can consider a reliable source of experts who formulate arguments regardless of whether they have minds or not?

Comment: The great thing about observations in phenomenology are that they should be intuitively verifiable.  You don't need experimental EEG thought-wave imaging.  That said, from Descartes to Husserl to Heidegger there were refinements.

Comment: i think that even if einstein was a zombie he was a very good physicist. sorry if that comes off as inane @Arti philosophy asks different things of us, but if you simply don't know IMVHO it's fine to place your faith in relevant authorities

Comment: We believe in other minds because of our common sense. Accordingly, when we rely on experts, we already believe that these experts have minds. We can go further and say that since we believe in other minds, therefore we can believe the experts and not delve into the arguments, but then all these arguments will be just additional justifications that will not be valid in themselves.

Comment: ok... so we only believe and understand experts based on common sense that contains the belief that there are other minds. i agree that solipsism is not common sense @Arti but neither is flat earth?

Comment: I want to ask this: 1. I believe in the existence of other minds, which is the best explanation for the behavior of other people. 2. This is the best explanation because experts think so. 3. So I believe that other people have minds. I don't really understand IBE, but I trusted the experts. This is circular reasoning. I believe in other minds because other minds said so. What do I have to do to stop this being circular reasoning and so that I can use the IBE to justify my belief in the existence of other minds.

Comment: You see, you can rely on the experts in everything except the existence of other minds because the existence of the experts themselves is called into question here. When you talk to a conscious expert, you understand that this is a reliable source of information who understands his business well. If you rely on an unconscious source, the question is, can such a source be trusted? If it is possible and it will be rational, then there are no problems, if it is irrational, then what to do?

Comment: i just don't see why you think that **all experts must have minds**. you may be right, but i reject that claim... maybe because i have learnt etc. things from experts that seem to work even if only i exist. anyway, good luck in figuring it all out @Arti

Comment: IBE (inference to the best explanation) is empirical, scientific, trying to deduce others by rationalisation.  All unnecessary because by direct experience your mind thinks in a culture with others.  By all means use your ruler and EEG to try to rediscover them.  Science begins with the ruler; phenomenology begins with direct experience.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's helpful to first consider some examples where it's clearer whether it's circular or not.

Example 1: "I believe that vaccines are beneficial because experts say so."
This does not seem circular.  We can in principle debate whether it isn't better to look at the evidence for oneself, whether the experts are in fact experts and trustworthy, etc., but none of this seems to involve circularity.

Example 2: "I believe that one should trust experts because experts say so."
This seems very circular.  If one doesn't trust experts already, this gives one no reason to trust experts.

So the question is whether your cases are more like example 1 or more like example 2.  To me, they certainly don't seem as circular as example 2.  But perhaps, for example with your second case, it could be circular -- for example, if the reason you trust experts is that it's the commonsensical thing to do; or perhaps if you are really considering a skeptical hypothesis such as "Is this all just a dream?" (see, e.g., https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691128597/dream-death-and-the-self), in which case these experts would just be created by your imagination perhaps precisely in a way to keep you believing in the dream.